# What's the proper way to make a Python 3 function accept presets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a function that takes three arguments:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass
```

and a class that provides presets in a tuple:

```
class Presets():
    preset1 = (1, 2, 3)
    preset2 = (3, 2, 1)
```

What's the proper way to make the function accept either three seperate arguments or one tuple of arguments?

Both should be valid function calls:

```
foo(1,1,1)
foo(Presets.preset2)
```

Comment: Often it's better to just accept three separate arguments.  People can easily use the "preset" by doing `foo(*Presets.preset2)`.

Comment: This is an open door to hard-to-debug code. As some answers stated, you should only accept one or the other, and it's the responsibility of the callers to comply. Calling `foo(*Presets.preset2)` is a good example.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is by using a decorator.

```
from functools import wraps

def tupled_arguments(f):
    @wraps(f)  # keeps name, docstring etc. of f
    def accepts_tuple(tup, *args):
        if not args:  # only one argument given
            return f(*tup)
        return f(tup, *args)
    return accepts_tuple

@tupled_arguments
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass
```

Now the function can be called by either passing all arguments seperately or by passing them in a sequence.

```
foo(1,2,3)
foo((1,2,3))
foo([1,2,3])
```

are all equal calls.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to just use an asterisk `*` to cause the arguments to be flattened when passed to `foo`:

```
foo(*Presets.preset2)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
foo(*(3, 2, 1))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
foo(3, 2, 1)
```